# Unable to contact the remote controller at 192.168.56.3

Tags: opendaylight, mininet

Good morning,

I want to set up OpenDayLight SDN Controller and Mininet in VirtualBox. So far I installed both and got them running.
My interfaces are:

- 1 NAT
- 1 Host Only Adapter

for both the VMs.
The Host only adapter has an IP address of 192.168.56.1.
OpenDayLight VM receives 192.168.56.3,
Mininet VM receives 192.168.56.4.

I am able to ping the two VMs. What I can't do is creating a simple test topology with the command:

```
sudo mn --topo linear,3 --mac --controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.3,port=6633 --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

In fact, running it causes this error:

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ sudo mn --topo linear,3 --mac --controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.3,port=6633 --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
Unable to contact the remote controller at 192.168.56.3:6633
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 h3
*** Adding switches:
s1 s2 s3
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s2) (h3, s3) (s2, s1) (s3, s2)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 h3
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 3 switches
s1 s2 s3 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet>
```

From the main site:

> Important troubleshooting - if you are running VirtualBox on the same
>   host/desktop where the controller is running, and trying to start the
>   virtual network on Mininet VM produces this error: "Unable to contact
>   the remote controller at ...", then the following resolves the
>   problem:
>
> In VirtualBox, go to File-Preferences-Network and make sure you have
>   at least one interface defined as Host-Only. Lets say its name is
>   vboxnet0
>
> In VirtualBox - Mininet Vm - Settings - Network, check that the
>   adapter is of type Host only , and is connected to the interface from
>   item 1 (vboxnet0)
>
> On your host where controller and VirtualBox run, do "ifconfig"
>   command to display all network interfaces on the machine.
>
> Search for the interface as in item 1 (vboxnet0 in our example) Take
>   the ip address specified there (most probably 192.168.56.1 - default),
>   and that is the correct remote controller ip address to use when
>   starting a virtual network in mininet vm as stated in the example
>   above (--controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.1) .
>
> If you are still not able to connect, you might want to consider
>   temporarily disabling firewall on the host running the controller (on
>   Linux, for example, iptables -F will do the job)
>
> Sometimes, the way you start the mininet is a problem, it does not
>   give error, but does not connect to the remote server. Here is a wrong
>   example:
>
> sudo mn --topo=tree,3 --mac --switch=ovsk --controller=remote,
>   ip=192.168.16.10
>
> Here is the correct example:
>
> sudo mn --topo=tree,3 --mac --switch=ovsk
>   --controller=remote,ip=192.168.16.10
>
> The difference is the "SPACE" between "remote," and "ip".

I don't see what I miss.

Thank you in advance,

Davide

Comment: This may rather be asked at here: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix that. 
`sudo ufw disable` both on mininet and ODL solved the issue. 
Thanks again jamo for the hint.

Comment: Please note that this disables the firewall ufw. If your computer is not being used as a server (with an open port listening to traffic), you will probably be fine without it

Answer (score 0):

do you have the openflowplugin features running on ODL? you can check from
the karaf console with "feature:list -i | grep openflow"

you can also see if port 6633 is running on the ODL VM. something like "netstat -na | grep 6633"

see if you can open a connection from your mininet VM to the ODL IP and openflow
port. I think it would be "nc 192.168.56.3 6633"

just a few ideas to troubleshoot, but since you can ping the ODL ip from your
mininet VM, I'm guessing there is something wrong with connecting to the openflow
port. so maybe it's not even open (feature not loaded, or blocked, etc)

Comment: Hello jamo, thank you for your answer.
1) Yes I have the openflow plugins running. (southbound, flow-services, nsf-services, nsf-model, app-config-pusher, app-lldp-speaker, java protocol).
2) running netstat -na | grep 6633 on the terminal shows me that this port is not open. I can't run the command "in the ODL" since it says that the command is not found. I opened it in the terminal, like "opendaylight@VirtualBox: ~$ netstat -na | grep 6633. 
Also, running this command from mininet doesn't show any output.
3) Also nc 192.168.56.3 6633 doesn't produce any output.

Thanks again.

Davide

Comment: I finally managed to fix that.
'sudo ufw disable' both on mininet and ODL solved the issue.
Thanks again jamo for the hint.